# AlarmManager not waking phone up in Air Mode (onReceive delayed)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Problem is that `onReceive` method of `BroadcastReceiver` usually "called" by `AlarmManager` is delayed until device is awoken by the user.

This has never happened to me, only information I have was is from the report sent by user. In the log I saw that in the first case `onReceive` method call was delayed by almost 2 hours and in the second one by about 20 minutes. In both situations alarm (and `onReceive`) has started just after the phone was awoken by the user.

Problem has occured twice in two consecutive days and user states it has never happened before. Only distinctive change in phone's settings was that Air Mode was enabled.

My code:

Alarm is set like:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
Logger.log("posting alarm " + id + " for " + formatTime(timeInMillis);
```

Broadcast Receiver's onReceiveMethod:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Logger.initialize(context, "AlarmReceiver");
    ...
}
```

Logs received from the user:

```
481. 20/05 13:00:04 v89: posting alarm 4 for 7:0 (in 17:59)
486. 21/05 08:58:00 v89: logger initialized again from AlarmReceiver

536. 21/05 09:04:54 v89: posting alarm 4 for 7:0 (in 21:55)
541. 22/05 07:22:24 v89: logger initialized again from AlarmReceiver
```

Is it possible for Air Mode to block phone's awakening somehow? Can I prevent it? Or maybe it is something completely different? Any help is welcomed.

Device is Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-I9305) with Android 4.1.2

Edit:
Just in case that delay could be somehow caused by the Logger, here's its code. `mHandler` is created with use of `HandlerThread`, so I believe it can't block `onReceive`, right?

```
public synchronized static void initialize(Context context, String src) {
    if (mInstance == null) {//wasn't null
       ...
    } else {
        Logger.log("logger initialized again from " + src);
    }
}

public synchronized static void log(final String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, text);
    if (mInstance != null && mInstance.mLoggingEnabled) {
        mInstance.mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //some database operations
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Koger, did you ever found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @ChriPf I wasn't able to reproduce it. Also I lost contact with the user and bug wasn't ever reported again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule your tasks with the specified interval don't use flags `AlarmManager.RTC` and `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` with method `alarm.setRepeating(...)`. Because in this case alarm will be bounded to the device's real time clock. So changing the system time may cause alarm to misbehave. You must use flags `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`. In this case `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` will serve as a basis for scheduling an alarm.

The code will look like:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + checkIntervalMillis, checkIntervalMillis, pendingIntent);
```

If you want your long running task to be executed when device in the sleep mode I recommend to use WakefulIntentService library by CommonsWare: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: Thank you for the comment about using ELAPSED_TIME - I was actually having problems with alarms starting after phone's time was changed. As for the second part - I have the WakeLock created later in the onReceive - problem is it seems like the onReceive is not called on time. I have added code of Logger.initialize - it doesn't seem to be a long running task, does it?

Comment: I have one suggestion. If user turned off his phone after alarm was set - this alarm is canceled. So if you have BOOT_COMPLETED receiver that re-schedules your alarm you can see behaviour as you described. Alarm will be scheduled to the later time than you expected after user reboots his phone.

Comment: that is not it - reboots are logged as well